# How do I properly use the Api Attribute in ServiceStack to name a service in SwaggerUI?

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

Using Swagger-UI and ServiceStack, I'm trying to use the `Api` attribute to name my services a little cleaner.

I am having a hard time figuring out where the attribute needs to be for it to add a `description` property to the api in the `resources` endpoint created by swagger.

I have a base request that is inherited by a few other requests for my customer end points. The `Api` attribute works only when placed on this particular request dto. If I move it to another, it stops working. Here is an exmaple of what my swagger page looks like:

[image]

Here is the code for that:

[image]

And here is the code that doesn't seem to work:

[image]

I'd like to have a friendly name for each service. Thanks!

Edit: I did track down some code in the ServiceStack codebase that indicates it is looking for the `FirstAttribute`. I tried testing by changing the order of things and didn't get the desired results either. I was looking at [AttributeExtensions.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/e4bbce12ae52cf2d1c6992db99d3d8a5bfc3c16a/src/ServiceStack.Common/AttributeExtensions.cs) if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[Api("API Description")]` or `[Description("API Description")]`
to add a Description to a single Service although this doesn't always map directly to a Swagger Route Description as the Swagger UI groups multiple routes under a single top-level route which covers multiple different services sharing the top-level route.

But you can specify a Route Summary with the `RouteSummary` dictionary on `SwaggerFeature`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature {
    RouteSummary = {
        { "/top-level-path", "Route Summary" }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi mythz, makes sense. Are you telling me that there is no way to directly set what swagger will display? Would it work if I added that to all the dtos of a particular route? i.e. all dtos with a route that starts with "/marketing" (which is what I assume swagger is doing)?

Comment: @IronicMuffin FYI I've added an example of using the `RouteSummary` feature on SwaggerFeature to specify a Route Summary description.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't realize that was an option!